# Problem converting svg to eps in inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg

I'm using Inkscape to convert an svg to eps. But when I save the svg as eps and open the eps using Gsview, the image is not placed at the center of the page, and even some parts of it are out of view.

How can I save to eps in a way that end up with the image placed at the center of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your aim? It seems to be more a GSview use issue than a conversion issue.

Gswiew tends to ignore the page size for certain kind of files (see [GSview Help](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/os2help.htm)), and sometimes you need to **change manually the page size** using the *Media* menu.

[image: gsview media menu]

`For example`, converting a SVG file ([Hurricane-en.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hurricane-en.svg)) in eps with  Inkscape and opening the exported file in GSview, by default some part are leave out of view (note that for a landscape image you need to check the *Rotate Media* option):

[image: default in gsview]

Changing the media settings you are able to see the entire image:

[image: same image with different media]

If you need to export the file as a PDF, in GSwiew you must select the *Shrink to fit Page Size* option to ensure that all your image is included.

[image: export with gsview]

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I thought that the image was somehow truncated. But how can I *control* the position of the image in the eps file in Inkscape?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how control the position of the file in Inkscape. Something better appears when you convert in postscript. Or you can improve the output editing manually the eps file and changing the values in the two rows after %%EndPageSetup. Some references: http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~mjr/eps.pdf, http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf, http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf.